# How do I remove first column in csv file?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv

I have a CSV file where the first row in the first column is blank with some numbers in the second and third row. This whole column is useless and I need to remove it so I can convert the data into a JSON file. I just need to know how to remove the first column of data so I can parse it. Any help is greatly appreciated!

My script is as follows

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import pandas as pd
import csv, json

xls = pd.ExcelFile(r'C:\Users\Andy-\Desktop\Lab2Data.xlsx')
df = xls.parse(sheetname="Sheet1", index_col=None, na_values=['NA'])
df.to_csv('file.csv')

file = open('file.csv', 'r')
lines = file.readlines()
file.close()

data = {}

with open('file.csv') as csvFile:
    csvReader = csv.DictReader(csvFile)
    for rows in csvReader:
        id = rows['Id']
        data[id] = rows

with open('Lab2.json', 'w') as jsonFile:
    jsonFile.write(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
```

Comment: Why are you not using pandas to open the CSV? And why are you opening the file twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know much about json files but this will remove the first column from your csv file.

```
with open ('new_file.csv', 'w') as out_file :
    with open ('file.csv') as in_file :
        for line in in_file :
            test_string = line.strip ('\n').split (',')
            out_file.write (','.join (test_string [1:]) + '\n')
```

Comment: JSON is [Better than CSV](http://jsonlines.org/examples/). And the OP wants JSON output, not another CSV file